# Abstract class overloading arithmetic operator

Tags: c++, pointers, abstract-class, pure-virtual

I'm learning c++ and I'm trying to do some polymorphism and operator overloading and I'm having some problems.

What I'm doing here is an abstract base class called Number and a derivated class called MyInt, I need to overload operator+,- in order to operate with `MyInt` numbers, `MyDouble` numbers... etc

After reading many posts I got stuck in this error `error: invalid operands of types 'Number*' and 'Number*' to binary 'operator+' cout << n + m << endl;` How can I make this work?

I know this works using templates but I can't use it here because the point of this excercise is to create something like `MyStack<Number*>` to hold *different data types*

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

class Number {
public:
    virtual Number* operator+(Number* n) = 0;
    virtual string toString() = 0;
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Number* n){ 
        return os << n->toString();
    }
};

class MyInt: public Number{
public:
    int value;
    MyInt(int e){
        value = e;
    }
    virtual ~MyInt(){}
    int getNum(){ return value;}

    Number* operator+(Number* n){
        MyInt* a = (MyInt*) n;        
        return new MyInt(value + a->value);
    }

    string toString(){
        ostringstream oss;
        oss << value;
        return oss.str();
    }
 };

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Number* n = new MyInt(5);
    Number* m = new MyInt(3);

    cout << "N: " << n << endl;
    cout << "M: " << m << endl;


    cout << n + m << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You did it very wrong. The immediate source of error is that both your `n` and `m` are pointers, and yet member `operator+` would want an object to be invoked on.

You could, in theory, perform a double dispatch (otherwise the syntax would be just ugly):

```
// define operator+ as a free function
Number* operator+(Number* lhs, Number* rhs) {
    return lhs->operator+(rhs);
}
```

However, while plus will be called for `lhs` will be called virtually, `rhs` will remain an abstract type. You will not be able to figure out what it is unless you do `dynamic_cast` for it - and that's just ugly. In general, your example is simply not a good case for dynamic polymorphism.

Comment: When I put 2 arguments it throws the next error 'Number* MyInt::operator+(Number*, Number*)' must take either zero or one argument
     Number* operator+(Number* n, Number* m)

Comment: Sorry for the ugly code, I'm new to c++, I'll look information about dynamic_cast. thanks for your response